# Unable to reference properties from one view in another view

Tags: objective-c, ios4

This is the code from the class within which I am trying to reference the properties from the other class(BIDDoubleComponentPickerViewController):

```
BIDDoubleComponentPickerViewController *dummyObject = [BIDDoubleComponentPickerViewController new];
NSString *selectedValue = [dummyObject value];
NSString *selectedSuit = [dummyObject suit];
```

However, whenever I attempt to access the variables selectedValue and selectedSuit, they claim that they are null, when I know for a fact that value and suit are not null within the other class. Here is the code that sets the properties in BIDDoubleComponentPickerViewController:

```
NSInteger valueRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:
                        kValueComponent];
NSInteger suitRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:
                      kSuitComponent];
value=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[values objectAtIndex:valueRow]];
suit=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[suits objectAtIndex:suitRow]];
```

Here is the code for the declaration of the properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *value;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *suit;
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new view controller, it doesn't load its view immediately. So if the code where you initialize `value` and `suit` is located in the `init` method, then `doublePicker` is still `nil`. Otherwise, if that code is located in `viewDidLoad` or `loadView`, then it is still not executed when you try to access `value` and `suit` using `[dummyObject value];` and `[dummyObject suit];`

---

**Edit:** (After OP's comment)

My answer is still correct because in the line:

```
BIDDoubleComponentPickerViewController *dummyObject = [BIDDoubleComponentPickerViewController new];
```

you create a new object `dummyObject` that is different from the view controller where the picker view was visible. So the values `value` and `suit` that you are looking for are properties of the other view controller and not the one you just initialized.

To solve your problem, you should not create a new instance of `BIDDoubleComponentPickerViewController` but retrieve the instance that holds the values you are looking for.

Comment: The code is actually located within the action of a button. The code for the other class is also located within the action of a separate button. I do make sure to press the button before debugging.

Comment: Your idea certainly makes sense. Could you give me a clue as to how to go about retrieving the specific instance?

Comment: I can't because there is not enough information here. You can post another question and explain how and where you created the different view controllers, how you switched from one to the other, whether you use storyboard, ... And ask how you can access one view controller from the other or how you can pass parameters from one to the other.